# Is there a solution to $a^n=c,b^n=d$, where a shares no factors with b, and n isn't an integer

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b,c,d$ are integers larger than $1$; $a$ shares no factors with $b$; $n$ is not an integer, and $n$ is greater than $1$, are there any numbers that satisfy the equations $$a^n=c$$ $$b^n=d$$

Comment: This seems trivial, e.g. $a=4,b=9,n=\frac 32$.  Or did you have more restrictions in mind?

Comment: Of course.  $4^{2.5}=32$ and $27^{3\frac 13}=3^{10} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are solutions. For example, with $n = 3/2$, we can find one with two comprime perfect squares for $a$ and $b$.

$$25^{3/2} = 125$$

$$36^{3/2} = 216$$

$$\gcd(25,36) = 1$$

Comment: What if $n$ isn't rational, so you can't use the power trick?

Comment: @JacobClaassen If $n$ must be irrational, my guess is that there are no solutions. Write the first equation in logarithm form:

$$a^n = c \qquad\implies\qquad n = \log_ac$$

This means that the second equation can be rewritten

$$b^{\log_ac} = d$$

I'm fairly certain the condition that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ will mean that there are no solutions to this that give integer-valued $d$. I will try to rigorously show this.

Comment: It would follow from the [Four exponentials conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture).  But apparently this is still open.  We don't know, for example, that there isn't an irrational $n$ such that $2^n$ and $3^n$ are both integers.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Wow, I am surprised that we don't know that